# MSsql update column from joint table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables ex. TABLE1 and TABLE2

```
TABLE1                TABLE2
ID | SIZE | VALUE     ID  | SIZE | SCORE 
1  | LOW  | 1.0       1   | MID  | 3232
2  | MID  | 3.0       2   | MID  | 2321
3  | HIGH | 5.0       3   | HIGH | 3232
```

what i want is to update TABLE2.SCORE so the values will be TABLE1.value column and the join to be SIZE.

```
   OUTPUT:
      ID  | SIZE | SCORE 
      1   | MID  | 3.0
      2   | MID  | 3.0
      3   | HIGH | 5.0
```

I tried:
`Update Table2 set SCORE=(select top(1) VALUE from TABLE1 join TABLE2 on table1.size=table2.size )` however this does not work I get this result:

```
 OUTPUT:
  ID  | SIZE | SCORE 
  1   | MID  | 3.0
  2   | MID  | 3.0
  3   | HIGH | 3.0 <---- wrong
```

Comment: What do you mean *"does not work"*? Did you get an error, unexpected results?

Comment: @larnu the desired output is wrong i get same score for all

Comment: table2.SCORE  column is int you can display as decimal value unless u alter the column to decimal (2,1) data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @TABLE1  AS TABLE(ID INT , SIZE VARCHAR(10) , VALUE decimal(2,1))   
INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT 1  , 'LOW'  , 1.0  UNION ALL    
SELECT 2  , 'MID'  , 3.0  UNION ALL    
SELECT 3  , 'HIGH' , 5.0      

DECLARE @TABLE2  AS TABLE(ID INT , SIZE VARCHAR(10) , SCORE INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE2
SELECT 1   , 'MID'  , 3232 UNION ALL
SELECT 2   , 'MID'  , 2321 UNION ALL
SELECT 3   , 'HIGH' , 3232 


SELECT * FROM @TABLE2

UPDATE t2
SET SCORE=t1.VALUE
FROM @TABLE2 t2 inner join @TABLE1 t1 On t1.SIZE=t2.SIZE


SELECT ID,SIZE, CAST(SCORE AS DECIMAL(2,1)) AS SCORE

FROM @TABLE2
```

Demo result : http://rextester.com/VFF59681

Answer (score 2):

```
update a
set a.score=b.score
from table2 a join table1 b on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE`:

```
update t2
    set t2.score = t1.score
    from table2 t2 join
         table1 t1
         on t2.size = t1.size;
```

You can also follow your pattern by using a correlated subquery:

```
update table2
    set t2.score = (select t1.score from table1 t1 where t1.size = table2.size);
```

There is no need for another `JOIN` in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do the `JOIN` in `subquery` you can directly express it as  :

```
update table2 
       set score = (select top (1) t1.score from table1 t1 where t1.size = table2.size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this:

```
update table2
set table2.SCORE = table1.VALUE
from table2
join table1
on table2.SIZE = table1.SIZE
```

However, to avoid problems, you will need to make sure `table1.SIZE` is `unique`.

Comment: As you can see in table2 that size can be duplicate

Comment: @Susang that does not matter. The source of data is table1. In table1 the value therefore should be unique. It is important to make the source of data deterministic, regardless of the number of destinations.

Comment: Sorry, the question seems changed now. You are right in this case as OP also wants to join with `size`.

Comment: @Susang No problem. I knew it from the initial command the op was trying to operate with: Update Table2 set SCORE=(select top(1) VALUE from TABLE1 join TABLE2 on table1.size=table2.size